# How to seralize array of object into index based post able data

Tags: jquery

I have an object something like this

```
var obj = [
  {
    "mainDC": { "id": 1, "name": "myFirst" },
    "mainDC": { "id": 2, "name": "mySecond" },
    "mainDC": { "id": 3, "name": "myThird" },
  }];
```

I want to convert this into serialized data which I can post while submitting form. I mean I want its generated result like this

```
"mainDC[0].id=1&mainDC[0].name=myFirst&mainDC[1].id=2&mainDC[1].name=mySecond&mainDC[2].id=1&mainDC[2].name=myThird"
```

is there any jquery utility method to get the above result?

Comment: what did you use for your server? Is it `asp.net`?

Comment: No, its Java/Spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

First, your format of object should be

```
var obj = [{
    "mainDC" :[
        { "id": 1, "name": "myFirst" },
        { "id": 2, "name": "mySecond"},
        { "id": 3, "name": "myThird" }
    ]
}];
```

My way for posting JavaScript object to server:

1. Serialize object to JSON format
2. POST the JSON data to server
3. Decode the JSON data to Object at server side

**JavaScript:**

```
// Object convert to JSON
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
// POST data to Server
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/api',
    data:json,
    success:function(){

    }
});
```

**Server side (PHP platform)**

```
if( isset($_POST['mainDC']) ){
    // JSON convert to Object
    $obj = json_decode($_POST['mainDC']);
}
```

Comment: I need to handle it on client side only

Comment: Then use JSON.parse() method parses a string to Object